# SSHKit::Command::Failed: ruby exit status: 2

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Выскакивает ошибка при попытке выполнить следующию операцию:

## cap production deploy:check

```
rvm 1.29.3 (manual) by Michal Papis, Piotr Kuczynski, Wayne E. Seguin [https://rvm.io]

system

cap aborted!

SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as sergrk@192.168.3.240: ruby exit status: 2

ruby stdout: Nothing written

ruby stderr: Ruby ruby-2.4.2p198 is not installed.

/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sshkit-1.15.1/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:15:in `rescue in block (2 levels) in execute'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sshkit-1.15.1/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:11:in `block (2 levels) in execute'

Caused by:

SSHKit::Command::Failed: ruby exit status: 2

ruby stdout: Nothing written

ruby stderr: Ruby ruby-2.4.2p198 is not installed.

/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sshkit-1.15.1/lib/sshkit/command.rb:99:in `exit_status='
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sshkit-1.15.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:169:in `execute_command'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sshkit-1.15.1/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:141:in `block in create_command_and_execute'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sshkit-1.15.1/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:141:in `tap'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sshkit-1.15.1/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:141:in `create_command_and_execute'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sshkit-1.15.1/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:60:in `capture'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/capistrano-rvm-0.1.2/lib/capistrano/tasks/rvm.rake:11:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sshkit-1.15.1/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:29:in `instance_exec'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sshkit-1.15.1/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:29:in `run'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sshkit-1.15.1/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:12:in `block (2 levels) in execute'

Tasks: TOP => rvm:check
```

**deploy.rb:**

```
lock '3.10.0'

set :application, 'phonebookapi'
set :repo_url, 'git@bitbucket.org:sergrk/phonebookapi.git'
set :deploy_to, "/home/sergrk/#{fetch(:application)}"
```

**Capfile:**

```
require 'capistrano/setup'
require 'capistrano/deploy'
require 'capistrano/rvm'
require 'capistrano/bundler'
require 'capistrano/rails'
require 'capistrano/puma'
require 'capistrano/ssh_doctor'
require 'capistrano/rails/migrations'
require 'capistrano/scm/git'

install_plugin Capistrano::SCM::Git

Dir.glob('lib/capistrano/tasks/*.rake').each { |r| import r}
```

**production.rb:**

```
role :app, %w{192.168.3.240}
role :web, %w{192.168.3.240}
role :db,  %w{192.168.3.240}

server '192.168.3.240', user: 'sergrk', roles: %w{web app db}

set :rails_env, 'production'
set :rvm_type, :user                  
set :rvm_ruby_version, 'ruby-2.4.2p198'
```

Comment: *"Ruby ruby-2.4.2p198 is not installed."*

Answer (score -2):

```
#set :rvm_ruby_version, 'ruby-2.4.2p198'
```